# Checking if a graph is bipartite is $O(n)$

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

It seems to me that checking if a graph is bipartite (or biclique) has deterministic time complexity $O(n)$, where $n=|V|^2$, since we clearly have to iterate over all the elements of the incidence matrix. Is there a formal proof that it's at best linear?

Comment: $O(|E|)$ might suffice, or do you explicitly want denpendency on $n$?

Comment: but given the incidence matrix of the graph, I surely would have to check more than $O(|E|)$ places to decide if the graph is bipartite...

Comment: Yes, the best algorithm may depend on the data structure ... With the matrix as input data structure, indeed $n=|V|^2$ is the natural measure of complexity of the graph. Giving a graoh as set of edges (püairs of vertices) might allow faster methods, but of course $|E|\sim |V|^2$ in the worst case.

Answer (score 1):

A graph is bipartite iff it is 2-colourable. We can check whether a graph is 2 colourable by the classic greedy algorithm. For each vertex, check all the other vertices and for those that are neighbours, check if any of them are coloured red. If not, colour it red, else green. Clearly this is $O(|V|^2)$.